# Ubuntu 18.04 - How can I make Chrome window resizable?

Tags: google-chrome, ubuntu, resize, window, user-experience

I am using Chrome in Ubuntu 18.04. 
But I cannot resize window, in either dimension. Nor is the bottom-right corner active for dragging and resizing to a certain size. 
I can maximize and un-maximize, but that size is predefined by Chrome. 
Is there a way to make windows resizable in Chrome/Ubuntu? Is this just a bug?

-- Versión 80.0.3987.87 (Build oficial) (64 bits)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I upgraded to version: `Versión 81.0.4044.129 (Build oficial) (64 bits)` and that fixed it. No need to restart.

Answer (score 1):

Launch Google Chrome and go to Settings from the hamburger menu (three horizontal bars/dots at top right). Then under Appearance select Use GTK+ theme

Also turn on the Use system title bar and borders option.

If it doesn't work right away, reboot your system once.

Answer (score 1):

In the Appearance setting, there is a "Use system title bar and borders" toggle button. Turn it on and you should be able to adjust the size of the browser.

Comment: Upvoting for giving an alternative that may be helpful to other people. Cannot test it on that scenario anymore though, so I cannot be sure that was possible or available for that version.